# Как удалить первую строку в файле? Python

Tags: python, строки

Пытался сделать

```py
f = open('file.txt').read()
f = f.replace('1\n','')
```

Но ничего не заработало

Comment: Откуда мысли, что не заработало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чет как то сложно

```
# прочитаем файл построчно
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# запишем файл построчно пропустив первую строку
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines[1:])
```

Вот и все

Ну и для любителей сжатых решений

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as source, open('file2.txt', 'w') as dest:
    dest.writelines(source.readlines()[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Вашим кодом вы только изменили строку, в которую прочитали содержимое файла. Вам нужно сохранить файл:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.writeline(f)
```

Более подробно: https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/#reading-and-writing-opened-files

Изменение строки у вас тоже выполнено не верно. Вместо удаления первой строки вы пытаетесь удалить часть строки, состоящую из числа 1 и символа переода строки (при их наличии)

Можно попробовать так:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.writeline(f)
f = "\n".join(f.split("\n")[1:])
with open('file.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.writeline(f)
```

Тут происходит следующее:

- вы читаете файл в строку f
- вы разбиваете строку на под строки по символу перевода строки
- удаляете первый элемент списка
- собираете все назад в строку

Comment: Я попробывал `f = "\n".join(f.split("\n")[1:])` и ничего не вышло мне выдало ошибку "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'" так же я попробывал  `f=open(file).readlines()
for i in [0,0,-1]:
    f.pop(i)
with open(file,'w') as F:
    F.writelines(f)` но у меня так же ничего не вышло

Comment: Что должен делать код в цикле [0, 0, -1]?

Comment: Я поправил код, должно сработать

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

text = "\n".join(text.split("\n")[1:])

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/env python3 

import shutil

filename = 'file.txt'
source_file = open(filename, 'r')
source_file.readline()

#файл будет сжат так что нужно переименование 
target_file = open('file.txt.new', 'w')

shutil.copyfileobj(source_file, target_file)
```

в этом варианте учитывается ограниченность памяти.

Answer (score 0):

еще вариант - просто указываем на первую строку

```
 with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = content[1:]
```

Comment: могли бы и в одном сообщении свои варианты написать, а не делать на каждый отдельный ответ

Comment: простите, увлекся.